# Border will not show in WPF Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to programmatically set a border in class that is derived from `System.Windows.Controls.Control`.

I set the `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` properties and made sure opacity is set to `1`, but the border still does not show.

```
_titleBar = GetTemplateChild("PART_TitleBar") as ChartPanelTitleBar;
_titleBar.Background = Brushes.Tomato;
_titleBar.BorderBrush = Brushes.Blue;
_titleBar.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

`ChartPanelTitleBar` is derived from `Control`.  Changing the Background works, so shouldn't the `BorderBrush` work too?

Comment: does your control HAVE a border?

Comment: No, it didn't.  I thought since Control has a BorderBrush, I can just set this and it should appear since it gets inherited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap your element in a [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx)

Comment: ok, nesting the control in a Border in the ChartPanelTitleBar xaml file did the trick,

thanks!